# How to install other setups before installing the main application using .NET's Setup Project?

Tags: .net, setup-project

I have created an application for which I want to create an installer using .NET's Setup and Deployment project. The problem is that my application requires certain setups (Drivers, SDKs etc.) to be installed before it. I want these to be installed first and then the main application. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In a setup project you can configure this kind of things by setting prerequests see: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Add_framework_in_setup.aspx

Comment: Prerequisites let you select from a fixed list of things to include (e.g. .NET Framework), but does it let you include custom items as the original poster will require?

Comment: Yes it does allow you to add custom prerequisites  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.80).aspx 
I tries creating a custom prerequisite using the procedure mentioned, but it does not appear in the Prerequisites. Is there something else that I need to do besides what is written at this msdn link